# textarea value height

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea that has a set css height of 85px.  A user might type lines of content within that textarea, and I would like to know how high the text/val is, NOT the text area itself.

Is there a way to check the height of the inside text including line breaks?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at this plugin - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/autogrowtextarea

Comment: Try to count characters, since textarea has cols and lines attr, you can stimate the height based in the lines of the text. I don't have a clear answer for that.

Comment: You can check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341496/javascript-how-to-get-the-height-of-text-inside-of-a-textarea).

Comment: To help guide answers in the right direction: WHY do you need to know the Height of the text?

Answer (score 1):

I would duplicate the content of the textarea into another element with the same width, **hidden**, and then get its height.

Comment: if its hidden... it has **no height**

Comment: and even then it's hard to say, because what to do if the scrollbar pops up.

Comment: It may have a height if you use `visibility:hidden`, and not `display:none`.

Comment: @Neal and @Rocket not true, see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RPBPF/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it, though obviously the mark-up is only generic and to be amended to your needs:

#### html

```
<div class="counter"></div>
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="tmp"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
textarea, div {
    width: 150px;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
textarea {
    height: 85px;
}
div {
    min-height: 85px;
}
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('textarea').keyup(
    function(e){
        var t = $(this).val();
        $(this).next('.tmp').text(t);
        $(this).prev('.counter').text('Height is: ' + $(this).next('.tmp').outerHeight());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cJ4gb/).

This could be amended to dynamically add, and remove, the `.tmp` `div`s as required. But I was trying to keep this as simple as possible, so I left it hard-coded.

References:

- [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) (and [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why you're wanting to do this.  If you are just trying to have the box increase in size to match the text, use one of many extensions such as:

http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

If this isn't what you're looking for, you can have a look at the source and see how they achieve this, and mimic it.